# Facebook share button / history.pushstate / wrong url

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-like

I am using the facebook like/share button

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/

to share the current url/page.

Furthermore my urls are created by using the javascript history.push function to modify the url.

```
    history.pushState("", "","/123");
```

So in the beginning my url is "example.com" afer a few seconds the url is modyfied and the new url is like "example.com/123".

The problem is that example.com is shared instead of example.com/123.
Is there a way to share the new url?

Thank you

Comment: If I remember correctly, there are at least three ways to include a like button, so you should probably show us the code you're using to include it on your page.

Comment: oh i´m sorry it is the html5 code found on the facebook link

Comment: Then you'd update the data-href attribute as well. `$('.fb-like').attr('data-href','/123')`

Comment: I tried that, the updating works. However the wrong url is shared.. Is it possible facebook does not allow such things due to security reasons for the users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply updating the `data-href` attribute on the button will do nothing – it has already been parsed, and “no one cares” any more about what attributes you might change afterwards.

You will have to remove the button from the document, replace it with a new one – and then call [FB.XFBML.parse](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) to get the new button parsed.

Comment: That is what i´ve expected thank you. How can i "replace it"? Would a fadeIn and fadeOut do the trick? Can you provide a code snippet that would be really great!